# Epicycloid is periodic if and only if $R/r$ is rational

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $R$ be the radius of the fixed circumference and $r$ the radius of the circumference that rolls without slipping around the fixed circumference. The general equation is $$f(t)= (R+r)e^{it}-re^{it\frac{R+r}{r}}$$
($t$ is measured form the centre of the circumference of radius $R$). Prove that epicycloid is periodic if and only if $\frac{R}{r}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Assume epicycloid starts at $t=0$.
Let epicycloid be periodic. Then it would need to circle the fixed circumference a whole number $k$ to get back to the start. That is, it would travel an angle of $ 2 \pi k $:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& f(0)=f(2\pi k)\\
& \iff (R+r)e^{i0}-re^{i0\frac{R+r}{r}}=(R+r)e^{i2\pi k}-re^{i2\pi k\frac{R+r}{r}}\\
& \iff R=R+re^{i2\pi k}-re^{i2\pi k\frac{R+r}{r}}\\
& \iff re^{i2\pi k}=re^{i2\pi k\frac{R+r}{r}}\\
& \iff e^{i2\pi k}=e^{i2\pi k\frac{R+r}{r}}\;\;\text{as}\; r\neq 0\\
& \iff 2\pi k\frac{R+r}{r}=2\pi k+2\pi k_{1} \;\;\text{with}\; k_{1}\in\mathbb{Z}\\
& \iff k\frac{R+r}{r}=k+k_{1}\\
& \iff \frac{R+r}{r}=1+\frac{k_{1}}{k}\\
& \iff \frac{R}{r}=\frac{k_{1}}{k}\in\mathbb{Q} \;\;\text{as}\;   k,k_{1}\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I don´t know how to prove:$\frac{R}{r}\in\mathbb{Q}\Longrightarrow $ epicycloid is periodic.
$e^{it}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. Now $e^{it\frac{R+r}{r}}$ has period $2\pi\frac{r}{r+R}$ or maybe I can write $e^{it\frac{R+r}{r}}=e^{it\frac{R}{r}}e^{it}$ and now $e^{it}$ has period $2\pi$ and $e^{it\frac{R}{r}}$ has period $2\pi\frac{r}{R}$.

I don't know how to sum up those ideas to conclude that the function $f$ is periodic.

Answer (score 1):

The implication you are missing comes simply from the relationship between the lengths of the circles in play. Because the periodicity of the epicycloid occurs only when the number of turns required by an arbitrary point of the minor circumference of radius r, say $C_r$ is finite to reach its starting point. In other words if $\dfrac rR$ is rational then after  an integer number of complete turns of $Cr$ on the greater circumference $C_R$, the arbitrary point in $C_r$ reachs its initial position. (Sorry for bad English).

Thus you need that the quotient of the lengths of $C_r$ and $C_R$ be rational to have periodicity and this quotient is $$\dfrac{2\pi r}{2\pi R}=\frac rR\text { be rational }$$
In the attached figure the number of turns in a case is equal to $5$ but in the other case it is infinite.

[image]

Comment: I've read it several times and it still sounds like you've proved: periodic implies rational, Maybe I'm a bit confused.

Comment: (1) Look at the first attached figure and take a point in $C_R\cap C_r$. You may notice that there are $5$ arcs of the epicycloid for you to get to the starting point. Each of these arcs has a length equal to the length of $C_r$ and the sum of the lengths of the $5$ arcs is equal to $2$ times the length of $C_R$ (that is, $5 (2\pi r) = 2 (5\pi R)$ that is $5r = 2R$ and this is due to the rationality at stake).

Comment: (2) On the other hand, if $\dfrac Rr$ is not rational, the initial point will never be able to return to its starting point because this would be equivalent to that $n$ times an irrational number gives an integer number (in the case of the figure, we would have $n\sqrt 5$ equal an integer and you know this is not possible).